# Run ClickOnce / .appref.ms application as another user? (Specifically GitHub for Windows)

Tags: windows, github, clickonce

I want to run GitHub Shell (part of GitHub for Windows) as another user, but I'm not sure how to do this. This is a ClickOnce application.

Using the GUI, there is no option to run it as another user when I right click on it.

Using command line, if I run a batch file as another user and have the batch file start the ClickOnce application, GitHub Shell appears to be running as the current user rather than the specified user.